# Azure - System Assigned Managed Identities for Function App

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I have a function app and need to give it permission to write to blob/table storage. I turned on "System Assigned Managed Identity", and I set the following permissions for it with the scope being the Storage Account I need to access.

```
Storage Account Contributor
Storage Blob Data Owner
Storage Table Data Contributor
Storage Queue Data Contributor
```

**UPDATE**
I remove AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET and AZURE_TENANT_ID and then I receive an environment configuration error. I am not running this locally or debugging, I'm triggering it through API Management.

`Executed 'Create' (Failed, Duration=1406ms)EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot`

^ The above link tells me I should add those environment variables back, but it seems like I shouldn't need them according to Peter Bon's answer below

One piece that I find very confusing (because I can't find good documentation on this anywhere) is that I am [required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-python#environment-variables) by Azure to include three variables

1. AZURE_CLIENT_ID
2. AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
3. AZURE_TENANT_ID

I am inferring that they are needed to actually allow my function app to access the storage account, which confused me at first because if I just gave it permission explicitly with assigned roles, why do I also need to create something completely outside of my function app to give it permission to do the thing I already gave it permission to do?

My question about this though is "HOW DO I MAKE THIS?" If I need to make an App Registration, what should the callback URL be? What should the API Permissions be? I gave it my best guess and did not get a satisfactory result.

```
App Registration:
API permissions -> Microsoft.Graph User.Read
Authentication -> https://<mydomain>.onmicrosoft.com/.auth/login/aad/callback
               -> ID Tokens
               -> Accounts in this organization
Secrets        -> Generated new secret to use for AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
Roles & Admissions -> Cloud application administrator
```

I then set AZURE_CLIENT_ID to be the app id of this App Registration, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET to the app registration's secret and AZURE_TENANT_ID to my tenant ID.

Then in my code, I attempt to do the following

```
var tableUri = new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}.table.core.windows.net/", storageAccountName));
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(options);
services.AddScoped(x => new TableServiceClient(tableUri, credential));
```

And it fails when accessing my table storage with the following error:

`Executed 'Create' (Failed, Id=<id>, Duration=2108ms)Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.RequestId:<id>Time:2022-10-21T12:15:21.6998519ZStatus: 401 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.)ErrorCode: InvalidAuthenticationInfoContent:{"odata.error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationInfo","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.\nRequestId:<id>\nTime:2022-10-21T12:15:21.6998519Z"}}}Headers:Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0x-ms-request-id: <id>x-ms-error-code: REDACTEDWWW-Authenticate: Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/authorize resource_id=https://storage.azure.comDate: Fri, 21 Oct 2022 12:15:21 GMTContent-Length: 279Content-Type: application/json`

and if I update the Authentication redirect to

```
https://storage.azure.com
```

then I get the following error:
`Executed 'Create' (Failed, Id=<id>, Duration=2349ms)This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.RequestId:<request>Time:2022-10-21T13:14:29.0955823ZStatus: 403 (Forbidden)ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatchContent:{"odata.error":{"code":"AuthorizationPermissionMismatch","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.\nRequestId:<id>\nTime:2022-10-21T13:14:29.0955823Z"}}}Headers:Cache-Control: no-cacheTransfer-Encoding: chunkedServer: Windows-Azure-Table/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0x-ms-request-id: <id>x-ms-client-request-id: <id>x-ms-version: REDACTEDX-Content-Type-Options: REDACTEDDate: Fri, 21 Oct 2022 13:14:28 GMTContent-Type: application/json; odata=minimalmetadata; streaming=true; charset=utf-8`

I am honestly pretty confused at this point, can someone please help me understand how to successfully set up system assigned managed identities?

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER**
figured it out w/ suggestion from Peter.. so, I'm not a C# developer, but have a programming background & am doing devops for this project, another group is coding the application. I didn't realize that they had specifically used new EnvironmentCredential(); in their code, since they emphasized always needing to use DefaultAzureCredential but the EnvironmentCredential forces the setting of AZURE_CLIENT_ID. This also explains our issue w/ using DefaultAzureCredential because it goes through the list like you linked in the answer, so it sees AZURE_CLIENT_ID is set, and doesn't bother going for MI even though MI has the right permissions.

Comment: what are the option you're passing here: `var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(options);` ?

Comment: I at first tried passing nothing. When that failed, I attempted to set it to be

var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId });

per the documentation, but if I did this, it seemed to completely ignore the clientId that I passed in

Comment: One of the main issues is that I know the other developers would like to do debugging on this, so I believe environment variables _should_ be allowed so that if you're debugging this from visual studio, it can take your local credentials, so in an ideal world, DefaultAzureCredential would behave how it's documented. Namely 1. It looks for env credentials, then just skips them if they're not there and 2. check for managed identity and use that if it's there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a managed identity you should not provide these env variables. It would also defeat the purpose of not having to store a secret. They are not required in that scenario. It is just one of the many ways `DefaultAzureCredential` tries to get valid credentials. See [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-python#defaultazurecredential). If you do not provide them, it will fall back trying to use a managed identity.

Comment: when I remove them, I receive the following error

Executed 'Create' (Failed, Duration=1281ms)EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot

Comment: And so that seems like it's telling me I need environment variables configured before I can use the function app. The link leads me to a section saying I need to add those three ENV variables. The first thing it checks in that diagram is the environment, which makes me think that it never gets to check if I have System Assigned Managed Identity enabled

Comment: Well, the docs point this out: *DefaultAzureCredential attempts to authenticate via the following mechanisms in this order, stopping when one succeeds*. So if the env fails it should continue with using the managed identity (MI). I suspect something might be wrong with the way the MI is set up. Have you tried disabling the MI and start over for a fresh attempt?

Comment: I did just now to be certain and I am still getting the same error. I'm wondering if I have something else set somewhere that's causing me problems. I do have ENV variables configured but it's mostly just api keys and endpoints and things like that which I had hoped to get moved over to a MI eventually. Is there any other information I can give which would be helpful in debugging this issue?

Comment: I do also have MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET set because I was using that to handle authentication between API Management and the function apps, do you think that might cause issues?

Comment: also, could it make a difference that I had originally been using User Assigned Managed Identity, and now today I've switched over to SystemAssigned? I switched because according to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/11400#issuecomment-620179175 UA MI can't dynamically determine which UA MI to use when requesting a token

Comment: figured it out.. so another thing to add, I'm not a C# developer, but have a programming background doing devops, another group is coding the application. I didn't realize that they had specifically used new EnvironmentCredential(); in their code, which forces the setting of AZURE_CLIENT_ID. This also explains our issue w/ using DefaultAzureCredential because it goes through the list like you linked in the answer, so it sees AZURE_CLIENT_ID is set, and doesn't bother going for MI even though MI has the right permissions.